# python one-line input referenced twice

Tags: python-3.x

How can I reference an input twice in a one line code?
Ex:

```
my_word=input()
print("hey" if my_word==my_word else "bye")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only referencing it once right now, so this is easy:

```
print("hey" if input().isdigit() else "bye")
```

Though you could argue that this line of code does too much, and may be difficult to maintain.  Breaking it into two lines makes maintenance easier, and for example it also allows you to set a breakpoint on the `print` line and inspect the value in `my_word` if you wanted to.

For academic reasons, here is one possible solution to evaluating an expression once but using it multiple times in one statement: list comprehension.  (**This is a terrible, terrible idea, and you shouldn't do this.  *I mean it.***)

```
[print(i if i.isdigit() else "bye") for i in (input(),)]
```